# LINQ null date comparison in Dataset

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a `DataSet` where I need to filter the collection where one of the date columns is not null.

How do you term this in LINQ?

This is what I have so far but there is a compiler error on the `w.CompletedDate` field in the `Where` clause.

```
Dim completed = From ins In InspectionDataset.Inspection.AsEnumerable _
    Where (Function(w) w.CompletedDate IsNot Nothing) _
    Order By ins.Field(Of DateTime)("UpdatedDate")
```

I have also tried it the below way but the compiler will not allow the `DBNull` comparison.

```
Dim completed = From ins In Inspection.AsEnumerable _
    Where ins.Field(Of DateTime)("CompletedDate") <> DBNull.Value _
    Order By ins.Field(Of DateTime)("UpdatedDate")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Field` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) on the [`DataRowExtensions` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348900.aspx) is not going to return [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx) for null values in the database (which is what you would expect using ADO.NET), instead, it checks for that value and returns Nothing if it is null.

That said, your query should be:

```
Dim completed = From ins In Inspection.AsEnumerable _
    Where Not (ins.Field(Of Nullable(Of DateTime))("CompletedDate") Is Nothing) _
    Order By ins.Field(Of DateTime)("UpdatedDate")
```